# Why there is no atomic_add_and_test?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, atomic

I read *Linux Device Drivers v3* and I'm now at *atomic* variables, there is operations that increment, decrement or subtract the value of the *atomic* variable, but there isn't an operation that add and test the *atomic* variable and I wonder why?

```
int atomic_inc_and_test(atomic_t *v);
int atomic_dec_and_test(atomic_t *v);
int atomic_sub_and_test(int i, atomic_t *v);
```

Comment: My guess would be because there is no such hardware instruction, because there is no need to implement that.

Comment: @KamilCuk Okay thank you but I'm asking why there is no need to?

Comment: @MohsenFakhrizadeh my bad, I misinterpreted your question.

Comment: What does `atomic_sub_and_test(-i, v)` do?

Comment: `atomic_add_and_test` has not been invented yet.